# Will files in Outlook Archive be deleted?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I'm wondering about Outlook Archive folder. When I Archive an email or so, will it be there permanently or will it be deleted after some time automatically?

Comment: Please clarify your request. What archive? Is this a business environment and company-owned email account? If so, you must talk to your company IT because they will have control over this. Is this just a personal account and you're using a PST or something like that? Then you will be the one deleting things.

Comment: It depends on if the desktop program of Outlook or OWA is being used and whether an Exchange email server is used. If using the Outlook desktop program with no Exchange server, there's two archive functions - one within the mailbox itself, showing an `Archive` folder within the mailbox, and a separate Archive PST data file that is used for Outlook's Archive/AutoArchive functionality. IIRC, this defaults to the Outlook PST data file auto-created when first running Outlook after installing, unless configured with a separate Archive PST data file _(which is how I've always configured Outlook)_.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the type of email account you have and the settings you choose for archiving. Here are some general points to consider:

Archiving messages in Outlook moves them to a separate folder, called the Archive folder, but it does not delete them.

The Archive folder is one of Outlook’s default folders, like Inbox, Sent Items, and the Deleted Items folder. This folder can’t be deleted.

You can archive messages manually or automatically, using the Archive button or the AutoArchive feature.

Archiving messages does not reduce your mailbox size, unless you have an Exchange or Exchange Online account with a retention policy that applies to the Archive folder.

You can access your archived messages from Outlook any time you need them, or from other devices through the Archive folder.

For more details on how to archive messages in Outlook, you can check out these articles:

[Archive in Outlook for Windows.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/archive-in-outlook-for-windows-25f75777-3cdc-4c77-9783-5929c7b47028)

[Archive items manually.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/archive-items-manually-ecf54f37-14d7-4ee3-a830-46a5c33274f6)

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you set Archive to NOT delete email (obvious setting in the Archive Setup), then archived email will be there "forever", that is, it will not be deleted.

I have Archived mail going back to 1996 from Outlook Express and then Outlook starting in 2001.

I do take the trouble to make a new archive folder in January of each yer and am now on Archive 12 (I did not start this practice until 2001).

Done properly (as I outlined above), Archive PSTs are perfectly safe.  Do back them (all your data) from time to time.